# What is the real path of webroot in Ubuntu LTS installed on Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I mean the folder I can access to manage files with Windows File Manager.

Comment: This is Windows Subsystem for Linux? This question on SuperUser might not be exactly what you want, but it might point you in the right direction: [What is the home directory on Windows Subsystem for Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/1185033/what-is-the-home-directory-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux)

Comment: Yes, I am referring to Windows Subsystem for Linux. Thanks, that thread answers exactly my question, that it the path: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs`